# Clickable drop-down menu javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, clickable

I have used JavaScript to create 3 clickable drop-down menu button in a webpage. when I click one button, script is works well. I can see the following menu is displayed. When I another button, the following menu is displayed. however, the previous menu is still there.

Here is my script. Hope someone can help me. Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".account").click(function() {
        var X = $(this).attr('id');
        if (X == 1) {
            $(".submenu").hide();
            $(this).attr('id', '0');
        } else {
            $(".submenu").show();
            $(this).attr('id', '1');
        }

    });

    //Mouse click on sub menu
    $(".submenu").mouseup(function() {
        return false
    });

    //Mouse click on my account link
    $(".account").mouseup(function() {
        return false
    });

    //Document Click
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        $(".submenu").hide();
        $(".account").attr('id', '');
    });
});
</script> 

// CSS

.dropdown
{
color:#000;
margin: 0px 22px 0 0;
width: 300px;
height: 30px;
text-align:center;
}
.submenu
{
background:#FFF ;
position: absolute;
top: 118px;
left: 515px;
z-index: 100;
width: 250px;
display: none;
border-radius: 6px;
border: outset 2px #0066FF;
box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.dropdown li a
{
color:#555555;
display: block;
font-family: arial;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 6px 15px;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration:none;
margin-top:-5px;
}

.dropdown li a:hover
{
background:#155FB0;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
}
a.account
{
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 10px;
color: #000;
border: ridge 2px #0066FF;
position: absolute;
z-index: 110;
display: block;
padding: 11px 0 0 0px;
height: 20px;
width: 300px;
margin: 0px 0 0 0px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration: none;
background: url(images-new/arrow.png) 275px 9px no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
}
.root
{
list-style:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-size: 11px;
padding: 11px 0 0 0px;
border-top:1px solid #dedede;
}

// html

<div class="dropdown">
<a class="account" >My Account</a>

<div class="submenu">
<ul class="root">
<li ><a href="#Dashboard" >Dashboard</a></li>
<li ><a href="#Profile" >Profile</a></li>
<li ><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
<li ><a href="#feedback">Send Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. How do you expect the community to trouble shoot this without the corresponding HTML and CSS..? a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be even better.

Comment: There seems to be something missing from the information. This code refers to a class called .account, and a class called .submenu. We can't tell how many dom items are in each of those classes. The mouseup and mousedown events that change the id attribute are confusing... what are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation is to do this with with a combination of JS & CSS.

You should use an active class to hide and show your elements:

```
//JS
$('.menu a').on('click', function({
    $('.menu a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

// CSS
.active .submenu {
    display: block;
}
```